# Count NLOC, TLOC, LOC per class on Eclipse

Tags: jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin, metrics

I'm using Eclipse;

Version: Helios Service Release 1
Build id: 20100917-0705

Do you have a good plugin suggestion for LOC counting which excludes auto-generated code?

Thanks lot,

Semanur

Comment: I'm not aware of anything.  How is a tool to know whether code was auto-generated?

Answer (score 4):

[cloc](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/) is a great tool for counting lines of code!

From their **overview:**

cloc counts blank lines, comment lines, and physical lines of source code in many programming languages. Given two versions of a code base, cloc can also compute changes in blank, comment, and source lines. It is written entirely in Perl with no dependencies outside the standard distribution of Perl v5.6 and higher (code from some external modules is embedded within cloc) and so is quite portable. cloc is known to run on many flavors of Linux, Mac OS X, AIX, Solaris, IRIX, z/OS, and Windows. (To run the Perl source version of cloc on Windows one needs ActiveState Perl 5.6.1 or higher, or Cygwin installed. Alternatively one can use the Windows binary of cloc generated with perl2exe to run on Windows computers that have neither Perl nor Cygwin.)

Answer (score 1):

There's ProjectCodeMeter which i integrated easily into [eclipse as external metrics tool](http://www.projectcodemeter.com/cost_estimation/help/FN_commandline.htm), counts many source code metrics such as complexity, arithmetic intricacy, logical lines of code, strings, numeric constants, and more, even estimates development time in hours.

See the "integrating into eclipse" section (about half way through the page):
http://www.projectcodemeter.com/cost_estimation/help/FN_commandline.htm

Best of luck!

Benjamin :)